# Way to retrieve input text and save it in a variable using useEffect Hook in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Is there a way to retrieve the value of the input text and pass it as a parameter in button events using hooks? This is the code so far.

Thank you for your help.

```
const TransactionDetailsPanel = props => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const options = [
    { value: '1', label: '1' },
    { value: '2', label: '2' },
    { value: '3', label: '3' }
  ]

  function checkQuery() {
    setQuery("AND TYPE='C'");
  }

  return (
      <div className="columns is-gapless is-marginless">
          <Select className="column is-3" options={options} 
placeholder="Advanced Detail Search" />
          <input className="column is-3"
                 type="text"
                 name="advancedQuery"
                 placeholder="Enter query here..."
                 onChange={checkQuery}/>
      </div>)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update the query state-value with a button-click, you can use a combination of `useState()` and `createRef()`

See this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-haibt-9d8y8

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const inputRef = React.createRef()

  const updateQuery = () => {
    const inputText = inputRef.current.value
    setQuery(inputText)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`you have updated your query to ${query}`) 
  }, [query])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input ref={inputRef}/>
      <button onClick={updateQuery}>Click</button>
      <h4>Input Text: {query}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So with `createRef()`, we create a reference for the `input` tag, which gives us access to the current text inside of it.

Then we have an `onClick` handler for the button, when executed we extract the value from the input reference and use it to update the query-state.

At this point you can run any additional logic you would like inside `useEffect` whenever the state changes.

Comment: Thank you, it is now working, but seems there are performance issues with this approach. Is there a way to just update the state after clicking a button

Comment: @Dan sure let me write a sandbox to show you real quick.

Comment: @Dan see my sandbox above and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you @Christopher, it is now working without performance issues. Btw, is the same approach applicable to retrieving the values in the React select dropdown menu value?

Comment: @Dan yes you can take the same approach using an option tag if needed. But it would be better to just use an onChange handler instead. I can update the sandbox to show you that as well.

Comment: That is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan cool see the updated sandbox! Let me know if you have any questions and please consider marking this as the solution :)

Comment: Hi Christopher, I edited the sandbox to include dependency: react-select, but there are errors encountered

Comment: @Dan the sandbox you editted should have its own unique path now. Can you link me to it?

Comment: @Dan gotcha, things are a little different with react-select. Instead of passing in e.target.value. We just pass in the entire selection. See this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-heyrovsky-jd3e1